# Open CV Multiplying huge matrices segmentation fault

Tags: c, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I am facing a problem while implementing matrix multiplication as a part of my project in OpenCV. The following is my code:

```
cvInitMatHeader( mat, 12300, 10, CV_64FC1, matrix);
cvInitMatHeader( matty, 10, 12300, CV_64FC1, mat_inv);
cvInitMatHeader( covar, 12300, 12300, CV_64FC1, cov);

cvMatMul(mat, matty, covar);
```

I'm getting a segmentation problem while running the code. Is it because of the huge memory it is consuming? Do I have any alternative option?Kindly note, mat and matty are filled with their correct values. I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your arguments the wrong way around. Try:

```
cvMatMul(matty, mat, covar);
```